# numeric updown control c#

Tags: c#-3.0

I am using numeric updowncontrol. For min and max values changed listening for these events
this.numDownMinLimit.ValueChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.numDownMinLimit_ValueChanged);
            this.numDownMaxLimit.ValueChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.numDownMaxLimit_ValueChanged);

step size set is 0.1

The eventhandler takes some time to complete.

If you keep the mouse pressed for a period of time and then release it, the eventhandler still executes with the previous values which were fired.

How do we prevent this scenario from occurring? I would like to discard the remaining events which are still in the queue, waiting to be handled, when the user releases the mouse button.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a look at the NumericUpDownAcceleration Class which handles this behaviour:

From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdownacceleration.aspx

> The NumericUpDownAcceleration object
>   is used by the NumericUpDown control
>   to optionally provide acceleration
>   when incrementing or decrementing the
>   control through a large quantity of
>   numbers.

Let us know how you get on.

Comment: did not solved the problem
once the updating the values are stopped. I will get the previous value also.